spacy tokenizer breaking 6M into 6 and M, similar to 6G, 6K, 6T
Not sure if it think these are short for million, Trillion etc
Can someone tell which rule is making this happen and how can I prevent it?
For more info, the other characters are not being split.
to replicate
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("12M")
for token in doc:
    print(f"{token.text} | {token.pos_}")


you don't need to change anything in the tokenizer. If it thinks that it is better to split "12M" into two tokens so it is how the tokenizer was trained.
Does this somehow ruin "12M" representation? Let's look at how this representation is created:
You have map between each token and token embedding (numeric vector)
token1 = "12" -> [0.222, 0.333, ...., 0.111]
token2 = "M" -> [0.111, 0.2222, ...., 0.444]
Then sentence embedding is sum of the two tokens.
sentence = "12M" = token1+token2 -> [0.333, 0.555, ..., 0.555]
So "12M" has it's own representation which is different from initial tokens.
